# Getting a directory outside symbolic links when running script nodejs

Tags: node.js, symlink

Let's assume the following example

- ROOT

  - config

    - my.json
  - releases

    - today

      - index.js
  - current (symlink to today for example)

i would like to include the json file in my `index.js` file using a simple `require`statement, `require('my.json')`

The nodejs script would be launcher using `node index.js` or `node fullpath/index.js`

The problem encountered is that the require path will always resolve to `releases/today/index.js` instead of `current/index.js`. Because of this the inclusion of my json file is not correct.

The following techniques have been tried, followed by the output:

- `__dirname`: `/ROOT/releases/today`
- `process.cwd()`: `/ROOT/releases/today`
- `process.env.PWD`: depending on the startup location of the script: `/` or `/ROOT/current`
- `require('path').resolve(__dirname))`: /ROOT/releases/today

`process.env.PWD` doesn't always give stable results and i was wondering if there is something that has the same result.

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this? I currently have the same problem. I am using path.resolve() on __dirname from a symlinked directory and I want the path to be specific to the project, not following the symlink.

Comment: Hello, I don't exactly remember if i resolved it or not (which most likely means i didn't). I did realize though that if i had to look so long for something like this I was most likely using an overcomplicated solution. In my case, this issue was solved by getting rid of the releases/current structure by using docker containers which allow a better/easier way of managing releases in my opinion and comes with extra advantages